# What is the determinant of Poincaré duality?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

For a complex $C^{\bullet}$ of finite dimensional vector spaces, one has a determinant

$$|C^\bullet|:= \bigotimes \left(\Lambda^{top} C^i\right)^{(-1)^i}$$

functorial with respect to quasi-isomorphisms.

Let $X$ be a manifold, and $E$ a local system on $X$, i.e., a vector bundle which can be described by constant transition functions. Fix a triangulation of $X$, and let $C^\bullet(X, E)$ be the complex computing the cohomology of $E$ using this triangulation.  Then Poincaré duality gives a quasi-isomorphism

$$D_E: C^\bullet(X, E) \to C^\bullet(X,E^*)^*[-\dim X]$$

and hence a map on determinants

$$|D_E|: |C^\bullet(X, E)| \to |C^\bullet(X, E^*)|^{(-1)^{1-\dim X}}$$

On the other hand let $|E| := \Lambda^{top} E$.  One also has a map

$$|D_{|E|}|: |C^\bullet(X, |E|)| \to |C^\bullet(X, |E^*|)|^{(-1)^{1-\dim X}}$$

Now the terms in the Cech complex $C^\bullet(X, |E|)$ are just the determinants of the terms in $C^\bullet(X,E)$, and the maps are correspondingly determinants, so there is a canonical isomorphism

$$|C^\bullet(X, E)| = |C^\bullet(X, |E|)|$$

> > $|D_{|E|}|$ and $|D_E|$ are two maps between the same one dimensional vector spaces, and so can be compared to give some number $\alpha(E)$.  What is this number?  In particular is it always 1?

Comment: Since Poincare duality generalizes to noncompact manifolds (or manifolds with boundary), you could generalize your question to that context. But now with more spaces, you have Mayer-Vietoris. I think it gives enough additivity to reduce to the case of simplices, which is trivial.

Comment: Local systems don't have to be vector bundles, e.g., one may have discrete coefficients.

Comment: What is the situation for the Grassmannian? Is the paper http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731659090033S of R. Proctor relevant?